# TryGetList Multiple List how to?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

```
 protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
```

SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

```
        SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
        query.Lists = "<Lists MaxListLimit=\"3\">" +
  "<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("StaffNews").ID + " />" +
  "<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("CompanyNews").ID + " />" +
  "<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("ManagmentNews").ID + " />" +
```

"";

```
        string.Format("<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE'></FieldRef></OrderBy>");
        query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";

        query.RowLimit = 10;


        DataTable dataTable = web.GetSiteData(query);

        Repeater1.DataSource = dataTable;

        Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Alexander I am trying to get from 3 lists, as i have described

Comment: Do you want to get information from several lists or you want to get list instances?

Comment: @Ilia Sokolov i want to get information from serveral lists

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve information from several lists by SPSiteDataQuery. See [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/401818/SharePoint-2010-SPSiteDataQuery-with-Example) for more details.

In this example the data is retrieved by this code.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(ServerText.Text))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        // Fetch using SPSiteDataQuery
        SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
        query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"105\" />";
        query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +  /* Title is LastName column */
                "<FieldRef Name=\"FirstName\" Nullable=\"TRUE\" Type=\"Text\"/>";
        query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";

        DataTable dataTable = web.GetSiteData(query);
        dataGridView3.DataSource = dataTable;
    }
}
```

The main line is

```
query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"105\" />";
```

How can you see this query is applied to the all lists that has "105" template id, this template is template for Contacts list, if you look at this line

```
web.Lists.Add("Contact List 2", "A contact list", SPListTemplateType.Contacts);
```

you see that Paul created the lists from Contacts template, thus values are retrieved from lists that are created before.

Try to google how to use query.Lists property in your case.

Comment: on that site that u send me. Were to he use c1 and c2 `// Create Lists
        try
        {
            var c1 = web.Lists["Contact List 1"];
        }
        catch
        {
            web.Lists.Add("Contact List 1", "A contact list", SPListTemplateType.Contacts);
        }

        try
        {
            var c2 = web.Lists["Contact List 2"];
        }
        catch
        {
            web.Lists.Add("Contact List 2", "A contact list", SPListTemplateType.Contacts);
        }`

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: i am using a repeater and not a grinview `DataTable dataTable = web.GetSiteData(query);
        dataGridView3.DataSource = dataTable;` how should i write if for an repeater? and which Id to " A List Definition from Content Type"

Comment: It's a basic operation. try to do research before asking this question.

Comment: I have updated my code above please se it dont now whats wrong

Answer (score 1):

Building on Alexander's example, the `<Lists>` element actually supports a `<List>` element where you can specify the GUIDS of the lists you want to query.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(ServerText.Text))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        // Fetch using SPSiteDataQuery
        SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();

        query.Lists = "<Lists MaxListLimit=\"3\">" +
              "<List ID="+web.Lists.TryGetList("StaffNews").ID+" />" +
              "<List ID="+web.Lists.TryGetList("CompanyNews").ID+" />" +
              "<List ID="+web.Lists.TryGetList("ManagmentNews").ID+" />" +
           "</Lists>";

        query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +  /* Title is LastName column */
                "<FieldRef Name=\"FirstName\" Nullable=\"TRUE\" Type=\"Text\"/>";
        query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";

        DataTable dataTable = web.GetSiteData(query);
        dataGridView3.DataSource = dataTable;
    }
}
```

More details here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.lists.aspx

Comment: ` query.Lists = "<Lists MaxListLimit="3">
                          <List ID="7A9FDBE6-0841-430a-8D9A-53355801B5D5" />
                          <List ID="3D18F506-FCA1-451e-B645-2D720DC84FD8" />
                       </Lists>";` // cant get this line to work

Comment: You will need the GUIDs of your lists. please see the updated code.

Comment: is have updated my code but i dont get it to work, should i have the code like have it above or is something wrong i want to bind it to the repeater